# Why postgres dump doesn't contain trigger functions?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to move database from local machine to debian server. I need to move at least whole schema with all trigger functions. How can I do that?

Comment: "*How can I do that?*" - use `pg_dump`

Comment: I mean, how do I include trigger functions?

Comment: You can't exclude them, so I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I have this exact same issue. When I pg_dump I get everything but the create function clauses. This causes the restoring of this backup to fail because "create trigger" clause refers to the function that is missing.

My SQL (first entity is missing, while second is in the backup):
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RefreshLatestData() RETURNS trigger
SECURITY DEFINER
AS
$BODY1$
BEGIN
  REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW LatestData;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY1$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER DataInsert
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Data
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE RefreshLatestData();

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I figured it out.

The problem was that originally I used:

```
pg_dump -t 'public.*'
```

This got everything I wanted, but not the trigger-functions themselves, also it didn't get the schema definition which was what I wanted.

Fix was to do:

```
pg_dump -n 'public'
```

That included everything